# How to edit and run python scripts after installing an API in Raspbian?

Tags: python-3.x, raspbian, google-home, google-music

I have been trying to follow the instructions on [Click here](http://unofficial-google-music-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#usage) in order to get my Raspberry Pi and Google Assistant to play music. I am a complete newby to all this so when each mouse click instruction isn't explicitly stated, I am lost.

So far in the instructions I am up to the Quickstart section. This is where I am lost. I have no idea where the scripts are they are talking about. Once I know where they are, do I just add my details into the functions and all of a sudden the Raspberry Pi will be able to play songs from my Google Music account?

Can someone please give me some advise on what I need to do so I am looking at the same information they are talking about in the Quickstart section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have no idea where the scripts are they are talking about.

These scripts don't exist yet. The API is an application program interface. It allows developers to interact with other programs. This API documentation assumes you know Python, and is introducing you to their API.

That being said, if you're not interested in learning python, I don't suggest you pursue this. Because on its' own, this library only gives you the power / option to control Google Play Music. It won't, like you said, suddenly allow the RPi to play songs. You'll need to write a script that awaits a command from the RPi, then plays the song.

Comment: I can code basic tasks in in Python ok but the concept of APIs is foreign to me. I thought this would be a good task to learn about it as it was advertised as an introductory level kit. So if an API is an interface, what does it look like? Where can I see the interface/get it to interact with other programs?

Comment: In this case, the API is the library that you installed. You use this library to write scripts. Instructions on how to use each library can be found on the library's docs page that you linked. Once you're finished writing your script, execute `python myscript.py` and you're done.